# Strain energy stored in the rod

Tags: homework-and-exercises, elasticity, stress-strain

**Question:**

A uniform rod of length l, young's modulus Y and cross section A, placed on a smooth horizontal table, is pulled by a force F applied parallel to the rod at one end. The other end of the rod is free. Find the strain energy stored in the rod.

**My attempt:**

If the table was rough(i.e.,had friction), the static friction force would have adjusted itself to match the external force F and hence two equal and opposite forces would have caused stress to occur in the rod. But here the table is smooth, so I don't know what other force will oppose the external force and how stress will be produced.

I'm not sure of this but if I assume that atomic force of attraction would oppose the external force and the rod is reduced to the center of mass(at a distance of $\frac{l}{2}$), the following strain energy would be stored in the rod:-

$$U=\frac{1}{2Y}(stress)^2A\frac{l}{2}$$
$$U=\frac{1}{2Y}(\frac{F}{A})^2A\frac{l}{2}$$
$$U=\frac{F^2l}{4YA}$$

The answser is given as $U=\frac{F^2l}{6YA}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no other force. The rod is being accelerated. The tension $T=F(x/L)$ in the rod will vary linearly from $F$ at the pulled end where $x=L$ to $0$ at the free end where $x=0$.

This situation is like a train of trucks being pulled by an engine. The forces on each truck are different, although if the mass of each is the same then the **net force** on each is also the same. However, the elastic energy stored in each truck (or in the coupling springs between trucks) depends on the **balanced force** at the two ends (ie the tension force in the spring) rather than the net force accelerating the truck/spring.

Answer (score 0):

Stress is produced due to the internal forces only, which is tension in this case. Now, the body is accelerating with an acceleration $a=F/m$. Tension from the left end is $T=F(x/L)$(Assuming force is acting on the right end).

Now, taking a differential element "dx" and extension on it as "dl", we find that:

$$Y\frac{dl}{dx} = \frac{F(x/L)}{A}\tag{1}$$

Now, using the energy density formula, we get:
$$dU = \frac{YAdx}{2}(\frac{dl}{dx})^2\tag{2}$$

Substituting (1) in (2) and integrating will give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t stand that this still hasn’t been solved in five years. Lol

---

The rod is being accelerated. The tension $T=\frac{z}{L}F$.

Set mass per unit length $q:= m/L$ , $a = F/ m$

A small section $dz$:

$$F’ = ma = qadz = \frac{m}{L}~ \frac{F}{m} ~ dz~ = ~\frac{F}{L} ~ dz$$

Check (accelerating force from differential tension):
$$F’ = T_R-T_L = dT = \frac{dz}{L} F$$

Strain energy in $dz$: $U_{dz}= \frac{T^2dz}{2YA}$

$$U=\int_{0}^L  \frac{T^2dz}{2YA}= \frac{F^2}{2L^2YA} \int_{0}^L  z^2dz$$

$$= \frac{F^2}{2L^2YA} \frac{L^3}{3} = \frac{F^2L}{6YA}$$

**Which is the Answer Given**

Answer (score -2):

The question seems not to be detailed enough.

According to your equations, all you have to find is the force "F".

I would say that there could be 3 things that determines the force:

1- The friction coefficient of the surface.

2- Drag of air due to cross section area of the rod.

3- The acceleration of the rod (F=ma)

But the word "smooth" suggests a simple situation to me. Besides, it will complicate things terribly to add frictional heat, heat transfer ratio, aerodynamics etc.

So I suggest just go for the F=ma by assuming that you accelerate the rod in "t" time to "v" speed.